# jQuery .ready() not executing on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I built a very simple site that pulls data from a weather API and displays it on the page with jQuery. It works perfectly when I run it on my computer, but on my phone it only displays the static `<h1>` headline without generating the `<p>` tags with the weather information.

I wrote my function and call it when the page loads:

`$(document).ready(function() {
        displayWeather();
    });`

I tried to integrate jQuery Mobile. I'm not sure if that's even necessary here as I don't have very much jQuery experience, but basically I tried loading my same function upon the `pageinit` and upon the `pagecreate` event.

I'm wondering whether my problem is a general problem with jQuery's `.ready()` on mobile or whether the reason might be a timing issue with my API call (`$.getJSON()`).

Comment: Can't say why it's not working without seeing `displayWeather`. Never saw a case where `.ready` function wouldn't work only on mobile. Also jquery mobile is helper for mobile accessibility, won't change anything with the core functions. Some hints of what could be wrong: 1. weather api is not accessible from the phone, 2. you're using some code that works on modern desktop browsers, but not with mobile browser, 3. you're using styling which doesn't work correctly on mobile. All these are guesses and probably shots in the dark, but can't do better without seeing what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just figured it out: the problem was not mobile devices but Safari's ES2015 support. I switched all my `let` and `const` statements to `var` and now it works.

Comment: If you're already learning ES2015, you should use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to compile the code to ES5 compatible code to make sure it will work across all browsers (IE9+ supported). Also keep in mind that there are many new APIs in ES2015, so make sure you include polyfills to support these features even in the browsers that do not support those yet.